# Pop alert on disabled submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a submit button which is disabled unless you choose an option

What I want to do it a pop an alert if the user didn't choose an option

i use radio button for options

i have the following code

```
            <form name="choose" action="index.php" method="post" target="_self">
            <br />
                            <fieldset >
                        <legend class="show_legend">Convert To</legend>
            <div class="radio_buttons">
            <img alt="" src="images/flv.jpg" class="format_button">
            <input  name="type" type="radio" class="blue_font" value="flv" onclick="javascript:document.choose.quality.disabled=false;document.choose.audio.disabled=false;document.choose.size.disabled=false;document.choose.OK.disabled=false;"/>
            <img alt="" src="images/mp4.jpg" class="format_button">
            <input name="type" type="radio" value="mp4"  onclick="javascript:document.choose.quality.disabled=false;document.choose.audio.disabled=false;document.choose.size.disabled=false;document.choose.OK.disabled=false;"/>
            <img alt="" src="images/wmv.png" class="format_button">
            <input name="type" type="radio" value="wmv" onclick="javascript:document.choose.quality.disabled=false;document.choose.audio.disabled=false;document.choose.size.disabled=false;document.choose.OK.disabled=false;" />
            <img alt="" src="images/avi.png" class="format_button">
            <input name="type" type="radio" value="avi" onclick="javascript:document.choose.quality.disabled=false;document.choose.audio.disabled=false;document.choose.size.disabled=false;document.choose.OK.disabled=false;"/>
            <img alt="" src="images/mp3.png" class="format_button">
            <input name="type" type="radio" value="mp3" onclick="javascript:document.choose.quality.disabled=true;document.choose.audio.disabled=false;document.choose.size.disabled=true;document.choose.OK.disabled=false;" /> 
            <img alt="" src="images/ogg.png" class="format_button">
            <input name="type" type="radio" value="ogg" onclick="javascript:document.choose.quality.disabled=false;document.choose.audio.disabled=false;document.choose.size.disabled=false;document.choose.OK.disabled=false;document.choose.audio.low.disabled=true;"/>
            <img alt="" src="images/webm.png" class="format_button">
            <input name="type" type="radio" value="webm" onclick="javascript:document.choose.quality.disabled=false;document.choose.audio.disabled=false;document.choose.size.disabled=false;document.choose.OK.disabled=false;"/>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
                <fieldset >
                        <legend class="show_legend">Optional settings</legend>

            <div class="radio_buttons"style="display:inline;padding:10px" >
            <br />Video quality:
            <select name="quality" class="radio_buttons" disabled="disabled">
              <option  value="2000000" >high</option>
              <option value="1000000">medium</option>
              <option value="800000">low</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="radio_buttons"style="display:inline;padding:10px" >Audio quality:
            <select name="audio" class="radio_buttons" disabled="disabled">
              <option value="44100" >high</option>
              <option value="22050">medium</option>
              <option name="low" value="11025" >low</option>
            </select>


            <div class="radio_buttons"style="display:inline;padding:10px" >Video size:
            <select name="size" class="radio_buttons" disabled="disabled" >
              <option value="320x240">320x240</option>
              <option value="512x384" selected="selected">512x384</option>
              <option value="640x360">640x360</option>
              <option value="854x480">854x480</option>
              <option value="1280x720">1280x720</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            </fieldset>
            <div class="radio_buttons">

              <input name="OK" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="" class="send_bt" />
            </div>
```

if someone click on the submit button it doesn't submit the form or notify the user of anything

i want to alert the user that he can't submit unless he chose an option

Answer (score 0):

Disabled elements to not fire any events. So you can't bind an event to show that message to the button.

There is a workaround however: Create an invisible `<div>` that has the same size as the button and is positioned right above it. Bind the click event to that element. When enabling the button hide that element so the button itself can be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

i worked around that and i got something is working for me

instead of showing the disabled submit button i made it hidden and it onclick it shows

i use the foolowing javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

the radio button code

and the submit button code

```
<input name="OK" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="" id="send_bt"  style="display:none"/>
```

so the sbumit button is hidden if someone click  on the radio button it show
and by that way i managed not to show  the submit button unless someone choose an option